# Is there a way to view from the lights perspective like in Daz?

Tags: light

Is there a way to view from the lights perspective like in Daz?
I would like to be able to then lock view to camera so I can control the light that way

Comment: I'm not sure how that works in DAZ, you need to explain a bit more and show some screenshots. But to use an object as camera, you need to selec the object and press Ctrl + Numbpad 0. [example](https://youtu.be/VeHEKmEPGy0?t=185)

Comment: "YES"....https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MYEPTZEOWp0 (Blender Secrets - Camera and Light Tip)...#b3d #blender #secrets

Answer (score 2):

You can:

- Select the light, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>, and in the *N* panel > *View > View Lock >* enable *Camera to View*:

[image]

- You can also select the light in the *Properties* panel *> Scene > Camera*:

[image]

Comment: Is there anyway to make it so that the perspective isnt so warped?

When I do this it becomes like a very low foca length type of look as opposed to the default 50mm look

and the camera in the scene is 50mm so i dont think thats the reason

Comment: I can't find any way to play with the focal length, except with the Spot, if you play with its Size value

Comment: dang, is this the only method to do such a thing then?

Comment: well it's not very common to use a light as camera, do you need it to correctly place your lights?